# The Flutter app unexpectedly closes when I use the camera on the device

Tags: flutter

I'm having problem with the camera and the android photo gallery. In debug mode it works on the emulator and also on the device. When I generate the APK and install it on the device, the problem occurs. I try to use the camera or select an image the app unexpectedly closes. I assume it's a permission issue. I'm using permission_handler: "^5.1.0+1" and I followed an example I found on the web (https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/versions/5.1.0+1).

I can't use the current version because my project is on old Flutter and I had a lot of difficulties to upgrade.

I really need help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mysongs_v2/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:mysongs_v2/global.dart';
import 'package:mysongs_v2/models/user.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class PhotoProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int userId;
  final String photo;
  PhotoProfileScreen({Key key, this.userId, this.photo}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PhotoProfileScreenState createState() => _PhotoProfileScreenState();
}

class _PhotoProfileScreenState extends State<PhotoProfileScreen> {
  bool _updated = false;
  String _link = "";
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  File _selectedFile;
  bool _inProcess = false;
  File imageFile;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  bool _isReadyToSave = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget getImageWidget() {
    if (_selectedFile != null) {
      return Image.file(
        _selectedFile,
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    } else {
      return Image.asset(
        "images/nickfrost.jpg",
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    }
  }

  getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    // request a user for permission first

    this.setState(() {
      _inProcess = true;
    });
    final image = ImagePicker();
    final pickedFile = await image.getImage(source: source);
    if (pickedFile == null) {
      Navigator.pop(context, _updated);
      return;
    }
    final File imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
    if (image != null) {
      File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: imageFile.path,
        aspectRatioPresets: [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
        ],
        androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle:
                AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("pfs:crop_image"),
            toolbarColor: COLOR_BUTTONS,
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
            initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
            lockAspectRatio: false),
        iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
          minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
        ),
      );
      this.setState(() {
        _selectedFile = cropped;
        _inProcess = false;
        _isReadyToSave = true;
      });
    } else {
      this.setState(() {
        _inProcess = false;
        _isReadyToSave = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("pfs:title"),
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: COLOR_MAIN,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              getImageWidget(),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Column(
                    children: [
                      new FloatingActionButton(
                        heroTag: "btnCamera",
                        onPressed: () async {
                          Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
                            Permission.mediaLibrary,
                            Permission.storage,
                            Permission.camera,
                            Permission.photos,
                          ].request();
                          print('permissao:');
                          print(statuses[Permission.camera]);
                          if (await Permission.camera.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                            // The user opted to never again see the permission request dialog for this
                            // app. The only way to change the permission's status now is to let the
                            // user manually enable it in the system settings.
                            openAppSettings();
                          }
                          getImage(ImageSource.camera);
                        },
                        tooltip: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                            .translate("pfs:new_picture"),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.add_a_photo,
                          size: 35,
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: COLOR_MAIN,
                      ),
                      new SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Column(
                    children: [
                      new FloatingActionButton(
                        heroTag: "btnGalery",
                        onPressed: () async {
                          Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
                            Permission.mediaLibrary,
                            Permission.storage,
                            Permission.camera,
                            Permission.photos,
                          ].request();
                          print('permissao:');
                          print(statuses[Permission.photos]);
                          if (await Permission.photos.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                            // The user opted to never again see the permission request dialog for this
                            // app. The only way to change the permission's status now is to let the
                            // user manually enable it in the system settings.
                            openAppSettings();
                          }
                          getImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                        },
                        tooltip: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                            .translate("pfs:select_from_gallery"),
                        child: Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate),
                        backgroundColor: COLOR_MAIN,
                      ),
                      new SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              new Container(
                height: 30,
              ),
              new Visibility(
                visible: _isReadyToSave,
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Spacer(),
                    new TextButton.icon(
                      label: Text(
                        ' ${AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("pfs:cancel")} ',
                      ),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        onPrimary: COLOR_BUTTONS,
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                          side: BorderSide(color: COLOR_BUTTONS),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context, _updated);
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    new TextButton.icon(
                      label: Text(
                        ' ${AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("pfs:save")} ',
                      ),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.check),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        onPrimary: Colors.white,
                        primary: COLOR_BUTTONS,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                          side: BorderSide(color: COLOR_BUTTONS),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (widget.photo == NOHASPHOTO) {
                          if (SERVER_NAME == '10.0.2.2/api') {
                            _link =
                                'http://localhost/api/$FOLDER_IMAGES_PROFILE/${widget.userId}.jpg';
                          } else {
                            _link =
                                'http://$SERVER_NAME/$FOLDER_IMAGES_PROFILE/${widget.userId}.jpg';
                          }
                          await updatePhoto(http.Client(), widget.userId,
                              "${widget.userId}.jpg", _link);
                          _savePhotoRegister("${widget.userId}.jpg");
                        }
                        uploadServer();
                        final snackBar = SnackBar(
                          backgroundColor: COLOR_SNACK,
                          content: Text(
                            AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                .translate("pfs:image_saved"),
                          ),
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        );
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                        _updated = true;
                        Navigator.pop(context, _updated);
                      },
                    ),
                    new Spacer(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          (_inProcess)
              ? Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.95,
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                )
              : Center()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

```
name: mysongs_v2
description: A new Flutter project. 
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter  
  query_params: "^0.6.0"  
  http: "^0.12.0+3"
  quick_actions: "^0.4.0+1"
  shared_preferences: "0.5.7+3"
  intl: "^0.16.0"
  flutter_i18n: "^0.20.1"
  provider: "^4.0.1"
  flutter_speed_dial: "^1.2.5"
  webview_flutter: "^0.3.14+1"
  truncate: "^2.1.2"
  screen: "^0.0.5"
  flutter_reorderable_list: "^0.1.3"
  url_launcher: "^5.4.2"
  infinite_listview: "^1.0.1+1"
  google_fonts: "^1.0.0"
  progress_dialog: "^1.2.4" 
  simple_tooltip: "^0.1.13"
  image_picker: "^0.6.7+12"
  image_cropper: "^1.2.0"
  characters: "^1.0.0"
  # location: "^3.0.0"
  font_awesome_flutter: "^8.10.1"
  flutter_masked_text: "^0.8.0"
  share: "^0.6.5+4"
  top_snackbar_flutter: "^1.0.2"
  material_floating_search_bar: "^0.2.6"
  qr_flutter: "^4.0.0"
  super_tooltip: "^1.0.1"
  permission_handler: "^5.1.0+1"
  
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

dependency_overrides:
   intl: "^0.17.0-nullsafety.2"
   
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - images/guitar.png
    - images/microphone.png
    - lang/en.json
    - lang/es.json
    - lang/pt.json
    - images/cover.jpg
    - images/nickfrost.jpg
    - images/logo_mysongs.png
    - images/chords.jpg
    - images/text.jpg
  
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  fonts:
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: CustomIcons
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/CustomIcons.ttf   
    - family: Magneto    
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/MAGNETOB.TTF   
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Manifest: DEBUG:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.mysongs">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="mysongs_v2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
     </application>          
</manifest>
```

Manifest: MAIN

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.mysongs">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="mysongs_v2"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    
    <!--
     <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="MySongs"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
     </application> -->
</manifest>
```

It didn't work as you can see the images below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Não funciono

[image]

Comment: The problem is the image_cropper widget. When I commented out the code the camera worked and I was able to retrieve the image and write to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is easy migration of the project to the latest flutter version.

1- Go to the terminal and navigate to the project location. Then update new `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`.

2- After this Fix, the code as some of the code will have to change according to new packages but most of it will be the same. I tried it. For me, it takes about 15 min to resolves updates and sometimes packages also guide you through if something is deprecated.

3- Create a new fluter project configure android and ios modules like permission added or other things which are packages requirements.

4- Then run the project. Will be run accordingly both on release and debug. but takes 1 hour. As I know from my experience it is worth it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Add 'release' block inside the android in app/build.gradle file like give below**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

**

```
Create if you dont have, 'app/proguard-rules.pro' file and add the following lines:
```

**

```
dontwarn com.yalantis.ucrop**
-keep class com.yalantis.ucrop** { *; }
-keep interface com.yalantis.ucrop** { *; }
-keep class androidx.appcompat.** { *; }
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but it didn't work, it didn't work as you can see the images... Did I do something wrong?

Comment: please can i see line 21 of your build.gradle?

Comment: `code` allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build' <=== line 21
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`code`

Comment: I added 1 image with the line 21

Answer (score 0):

Add Lines to your Manifest: MAIN ..

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Because you provide all permission for the debug mode. if you only provide permission on the main manifest file it will work for both modes.